# Cant force website not to render in IE7 in IE8

Tags: asp.net, iis, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-7

I have a webiste that is going into IE7 Mode in IE8 and I dont want it to be

I've tryed adding the meta tag to force it but IE just ignores it when on the server.
I've also tried adding it to the Web.config and the root Web.config of the server.

Can anyone help as the site does not render correctly under IE7 mode in IE8 and we use IE8

Answer (score 1):

Adding meta tag or any other configuration change won't help you. Your markup is not adhering to XHTML standards and some other markup validation is also failing hence IE8 is triggering quirks mode and going to IE 7 mode. You need to fix your markup.

Try running your page through http://validator.w3.org/dev/tests/ and that should help you.